# Which class throws IllegalArgumentException when sorting with JRE 1.7?

Tags: java, sorting, java-7, illegalargumentexception

I got hit with the (apparently infamous) IllegalArgumentException using Collections.sort() in Java7
Thanks to SO I understand the cause, which is basically (cough) poor code.
The thing is, I cannot reproduce the Exception myself. I did some jdk source code digging, and located which class is throwing that exception. The idea is to create the according Test Case.
Here is the code, by the way
< pride level="0" >

```
@Override
public int compareTo( Symbol other) {
    if( this.lastUse == 0) {
        if( other.lastUse != 0) return (int)( -DateMicros.ONE_DAY);
    } else if( other.lastUse == 0) {
        return ( int)DateMicros.ONE_DAY;
    }
    return ( int)( this.lastUse - other.lastUse);
}
```

< /pride >
On top of this, "lastUse" gets assigned timestamps in microseconds and milliseconds (yes mixed) which gives a superb int overflow spillage

The actual question is:
**What Values Would make This Code Crash?** to get a proper test case down the road.

Update with stack trace:

```
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without looking at the stacktrace itself.

But the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) mentions that the method itself can throw the exception.

> (optional) if the implementation detects that the natural ordering of the list elements is found to violate the Comparable contract

**Update**

It looks like because your object does not fulfull the `Comparable` consistency requirement:

> The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C. Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false.

Comment: Doh ... Updating with stack trace

Comment: Does that mean you need to implement equals() consistent with compareTo() to fill the contract?

Comment: @MonoThreaded: Yes exactly, make your `compareTo` and `equals` consistent as described above and see.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the crash is caused by the integer overflow, which was not supposed to be however. 
This was identified as bug ,  and it gives you the walkaround too.

```
http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7075600
```

Try this as temporary fix :

```
Adding -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true to my eclipse.ini does seem to have resolved the issue.
```

You can find this fix in the same link I posted though.

Also visit this `http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6923200` , which was the same kind of bug reported prior to the first link, however it was closed since they were unable to create the same problem repeatedly.

Comment: That bug is related to this one "swing LayoutComparator breaks transitivity that may lead to IllegalArgumentException". @MonoThreaded: You haven't posted the whole stacktrace? Not able to figure out if yours also is swing related.

Answer (score 2):

From [Java SE 7 and JDK 7 Compatibility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#source)

**Area:** API: Utilities

**Synopsis:** Updated sort behavior for Arrays and Collections may throw an IllegalArgumentException

**Description:** The sorting algorithm used by `java.util.Arrays.sort` and (indirectly) by `java.util.Collections.sort` has been replaced. The new sort implementation may throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if it detects a `Comparable that violates the Comparable contract`. The previous implementation silently ignored such a situation.
If the previous behavior is desired, you can use the new system property, `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort`, to restore previous mergesort behavior.
Nature of Incompatibility: behavioral

RFE: 6804124

So  correct implementation should be like

```
  public int compareTo( Symbol other) {
        if( this.lastUse == other.lastUse) {
           return 0;
        } else if( other.lastUse>this.lastUse) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

References

1. [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Comment: Once again, I understand the compatibility problem. Thanks though.

Comment: @MonoThreaded Added correct implementation for your reference